# What programs does the GNOME desktop environment start, after loading Metacity?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, nautilus, openbox, cairo-dock

I installed Ubuntu full version. It's shipped with the GNOME desktop environment.

Now I want to start some kind of experiment for my netbook, having only a selection of applications for a custom, lightweight desktop environment. Actually I'm running beside OpenBox a taskbar called "Docky".

So I'm using the OpenBox session selectable with GDM that is being shipped with the installation of the OpenBox Ubuntu package.

I start OpenBox with a `autostart.sh` looking like this:

```
nautilus --no-default-window &
docky --nvidia
```

The bad thing is, everything looks quite ugly. It looks like, I need to start some additional programs of the GNOME package to have everything back beautiful. I do not need the Gnome-panel and not the new taskbar GNOME has on the left, but I guess there will be a GNOME application that is responsible for loading all libs and themes.

Can anybody tell me these programs, I need also to load with my `autostart.sh` to get back the beauty of GNOME forms and buttons?

To make clear what I mean:

[This screenshot is my OpenBox-session](http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/6554/nognome.png)

[This is my standard Ubuntu-session](http://img253.imageshack.us/img253/6606/withgnome.png)

Look at both screenshots and read it's explanation. You will see what I mean.

Thanks.

Comment: What Ubuntu Version are you using

Comment: And why don't you just start the Openbox Session? instead of starying Gnome and then Openbox on top of it

Comment: 11.10 --- no, it is not Gnome ontop OpenBox, it is the OpenBox session with just OpenBox, now I need to start the Gnome support manually (or like above by a script)

Comment: Uhmm ok, now What is that you are referring to as "Gnome"? Gnome Shell? Gnome fallback? What? The classic panel is Gnome 2 and is no longer in 11.10 by default

Comment: see editing above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it!

This is how your `autostart.sh` in `~/.config/openbox/` has to look like:

```
gnome-session &
xcompmgr &
nautilus --no-default-window &
docky --nvidia
```

`gnome-session` is for loading all gnome themes, icons and libs.
`xcompmgr` is for the transparency effects, try `sudo apt-get install xcompmgr` to get it.
Then I start nautilus to replace OpenBox' right click on desktop and docky, in my case with nvidia support.

Comment: what you get is an almost lightweight desktop environment that reminds to Windows7